# Can I count number of rows in joined table?

Tags: mysql

Like this:

```
SELECT s.*, count( logs.* ) as ssh_count
FROM servers s
LEFT JOIN logs ON s.ip_address = logs.server_ip
```

But I get an error with that query:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* ) as ssh_count FROM servers s LEFT JOIN logs ON s.ip_address = logs.server_ip LIMIT' at line 1`

I think that's because you can't address a table in the count function.

I can do this using a subquery, but that will likely slowly down the query.
What is a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adress a table column, but you can't address `table.*`, you can do this for example:

```
SELECT s.*, count( logs.server_ip ) as ssh_count
FROM servers s
LEFT JOIN logs ON s.ip_address = logs.server_ip
```